# Preventing Screenshots

Tags: excel, security, google-apps-script, google-sheets, screenshot

Ok, I know this is probably impossible but I currently have a spreadsheet on google sheets that I would like to share with a large group of people, but unfortunately the last time I did this there were countless people that took the information and claimed it as their own and other such problems. No one had a problem downloading google drive to access the spreadsheet and did so without complaint. I've since removed that sheet and completely changed the layout and information. I was wondering if there was any way to make things more difficult for anyone that would like to screenshot the sheet. I know that anyone that looks into it can figure out how to screenshot anything, but I honestly don't think they will, and if they decide to go through more steps just to screenshot the info then o well. It's the internet and some things can't be prevented.

TL,DR; Can I add anything to my google spreadsheet to make taking a screenshot more difficult. I'm also willing to move the spreadsheet to another program if that is required, as long as I can still share the information. Everyone that the sheet is for will download the app to access it.(well, 98% of them)  I know it sounds silly, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to state that I have looked for awhile and haven't been able to find an answer for my particular question but if this has an answer somewhere and I missed it please direct me there and i will remove this question., and I would also like to say that "you can't stop someone from taking a screenshot, deal with it" isn't required.

Thanks you to anyone that read this. Hopefully someone has some insight and hopefully this helps others with any similar problems.

Comment: One thing i can think of is adding a watermark picture. I wasn't able to find such option. Maybe it can be regular picture, shopped (more transparency, less color,...), then added as picture.

Comment: It looks to me like you've decided upon a solution without explaining the problem.  For example, you say you want to prevent screenshots instead of, say, asking how to filter and present only the most relevant information to a given user.  If you also provide some context then that would help us to help you.  For instance, when I saw your post, I imagined (incorrectly?) something like a list of private addresses that a group should have access to but should also be prevented from easily distributing. See these [guidelines for posing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can't stop someone from taking a screenshot. Deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a client side script that gets the data feed from a spreadsheet (make sure the sheet is published and set to anyone with the link can view). With the data feed you could do anything, such as a table that disappears after a few seconds, or add a watermark as mentioned above. You could also render the data in hard to copy format such as light grey text on a white background.

```js
//https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OY18xmnT-O4AWzGDC63RvzzmNgyKHOnuvq-RX6M_6xw/edit#gid=0

var spreadsheetID = "1OY18xmnT-O4AWzGDC63RvzzmNgyKHOnuvq-RX6M_6xw";
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/1/public/values?alt=json";
$.getJSON(url, function(incomingData) {
 data = incomingData;
    var entry = data.feed.entry;
    showData(entry)
});

function showData(entry){
  for (var items in entry){
  console.log(entry[items].gsx$fruit.$t +": "+ entry[items].gsx$number.$t )
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```